# Custom ordering based on order ID and timestamp fields

Tags: sql

SQL friends,
What is the best way to create a column for order/sequence numbering based on two columns in a table

1. Order ID
2. Action TimeStamp
   Looking to create custom column based on chronological order using timestamp.

| order_id | action_timestamp | desired_output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | 11/16/2020 2:04:34 PM | 1 |
| 1111 | 11/16/2020 2:13:03 PM | 2 |
| 1111 | 12/3/2020 4:11:59 PM | 3 |
| 2222 | 11/16/2020 3:26:11 PM | 1 |
| 2222 | 11/17/2020 6:47:00 PM | 2 |
| 2222 | 12/3/2020 4:54:29 PM | 3 |
| 2222 | 12/10/2020 8:29:23 PM | 4 |

[See Image Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxY4k.png)

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your problem:

```
SELECT * from table_name 
ORDER BY order_id, action_timestamp
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
Order_ID,
action_timestamp, 
row_number() over (partition by order_id order by action_timestamp) as desired_output 
from your_table order by Order_ID;
```

Comment: @pdhil  please can mark this accepted ,  this will close the question and helps stack overflow track open/closed questions